# Tell Typescript about Global Property

Tags: typescript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am using Dynamics 365 and creating a custom control. By creating this control, there is a property that I can access at window.parent.Xrm. Xrm is an object, and I have the d.ts file that properly describes it.

However if I try to access it, Typescript gives me an error:

`Property Xrm does not exist on type 'Window'`

This makes sense to me: `window.parent` is Type `Window`, and that type doesn't know about this Dynamics 365 specific property.

If it was just window, I can see that I could extend the interface of `Window`, something like:

```
interface Foo : extends Window {
    Xrm: Xrm<Bar>;//my definition goes here
}
```

But I don't want to extend `Window`, it's `window.parent` I want to extend and I can't quite seem to get my head around how I would set that.

Comment: Why not just access it by typecasting `window.parent`, like so: `(window.parent as Foo).Xrm`?

Comment: either global augmentation or `export as namespace`